# Oracle: transpose table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the following query

```
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL
```

AND I'd like something like

```
SELECT TRANSPOSE(SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL)
```

Which outputs the same as

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
```

I'd like it to swap lines with columns.

Comment: Which version of Oracle is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype` and `XMLTABLE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW/*' passing  dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL') 
              COLUMNS val VARCHAR(100) PATH '.');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=05b7d944d550de041cc6825aa8101d01)**

Advantage over unpivot - there is no need to specify column list in advance

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is Oracle 11, you can use UNPIVOT:

```
select no from
(SELECT 1 a, 2 b FROM DUAL) dummy
unpivot (no for col in (a as 'A', b as 'B'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Oracle 11g, the best solution is the one you provided:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
```